# Returning the 4 most recent orders for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to return the 4 most recent for each CustomerID. So far I have:

Use Northwind_2012

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate
FROM Orders
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

From here I want to restrict it to the 4 most recent OrderDate's for each CustomerID. Where do I go from here in order to achieve this, as I have also tried using PARTITION BY and ROW_NUMBER but haven't been able to accomplish it yet.

```
CustomerID OrderDate
ALFKI 2007-08-25 00:00:00.000
ALFKI 2007-10-03 00:00:00.000
ALFKI 2007-10-13 00:00:00.000
ALFKI 2008-01-15 00:00:00.000
ALFKI 2008-03-16 00:00:00.000
ALFKI 2008-04-09 00:00:00.000
ANATR 2008-03-04 00:00:00.000
ANATR 2007-11-28 00:00:00.000
ANATR 2007-08-08 00:00:00.000
ANATR 2006-09-18 00:00:00.000
ANTON 2006-11-27 00:00:00.000
ANTON 2007-04-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: hutfut - I made big mistake. I can't fix my incorrect query at the moment. see the other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested, works:

(assuming a "OrderID" primary key:

```
SELECT CustomerId, OrderDate
FROM Orders as ExtOrders
WHERE OrderId IN (
     SELECT TOP 4 OrderId
     FROM Orders
     WHERE CustomerId LIKE ExtOrders.CustomerId
     ORDER BY OrderDate DESC)
ORDER BY CustomerId; -- Might not work in SQLFiddle if CustomerId is text
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25b07/8)

Comment: I checked yours in SQL Server 2012 and for some reason it's not giving me the output that shows in the SQLFiddle which shows correctly what I was looking for, not sure what's wrong and if it's something on my end.

Comment: Was at first not giving me what I needed but I added another ORDER BY at the end and ordered it by customerid and it came out as i expected in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`, using either a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Orders
     ) o
WHERE seqnum <= 4
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: `OrderDate,` fix needed and error - Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER'.

Comment: Your's has some minor syntax errors around ROW_NUMBER, FROM, and PARTITION. I fixed the FROM by deleting the last comma before it, the ROW I fixed by deleting the o.* as well as the o after the last parentheses, but I now get some error on the where clause now for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Edit, I didn't read the question thoroughly. try this:

```
Use Northwind_2012
WITH e
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
            ) AS rownum
        ,CustomerID
        ,OrderDate
    FROM Orders
    )
SELECT CustomerID
    ,OrderDate
FROM e
WHERE rownum <= 4
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afe40/11/0

Comment: Not my -1, but the question requires not the top 4, but the top 4 *of each* CustomerID.

Comment: Top is incorrect. You will get TOP 4 Customer, OrderDate combinations and NOT TOP 4 Customer, OrderDate combination for EACH customer.

Comment: error - Invalid column name 'rownum'. and still wrong output.